# Notepad- Select only one column

Tags: notepad, selection, column

I want to select only one column in my txt file. This is the sample of my file, its contain about 15k line i only want to select date column how i change a copy paste only on column...

```
Date        Precip[mm/day]  Temp[C] Q[mm/day]           
20510101    0.00001     267.427     0           
20510102    0.000082    268.3863    0           
20510103    0.000001    264.1161    0           
20510104    0.000015    265.132     0
```

Comment: It's not possible with notepad. Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) instead

Comment: In case you have MS Excel or Similar Products, you can also copy-paste this text to a new sheet and select the column easily there !

Answer (score 1):

Paste to Excel, and select the pasted column- go to **Data**- **Text to Columns**-Select the **Delimited**- Check **Space**-**Finish**- now you can only select the Date column:

[image]
[image]
[image]